# How do i make text show up on one half of the page and different text show up on the other half of the page without using tables?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add text to one side of the page, and different text in different side of the page, how do I do this without creating a table? For example this website: [http://i.imgur.com/lTASv3H.png](https://i.imgur.com/lTASv3H.png) has its text divided into two parts one with the address, and one with the opening hours. Website for reference and thanks in advance: http://goldengreatwallmapleglen.com

Comment: do you want to duplicate the footer or just want to make a row split into two columns?

Comment: just a row split into two columns

Comment: what do you mean by table? you mean '<table>' right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common way to split a row into columns is to use s

**HTML**

You just need to make two s with the same class

**CSS**

to make those div split a row into 2, you need to give them the following style:

```
width: 50%;
display: table-cell;
```

**EXPLANATION**

`width: 50%` is to reduce it's width into half of the original size

`display: table-cell` is to make sure that those divs will show in the same line but not in different lines

**DEMO**

```css
.half {
  width:50%;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="half">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
</div>
<div class="half">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
</div>
```

Comment: OP does not want to use tables.

Comment: @RalphDavidAbernathy I think that what he mean by table is he don't want to use <table>

Comment: Yes this is perfect thanks! Sorry if i made my question unclear

Answer (score 0):

you can make two divs each of them with

> width = "50%"

in this case you will divide your website screen into two equal parts

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="column-left">Left</div>
  <div class="column-right">Right</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.column-left,
.column-right {
  width: 50%;
}
```

I hope that helps!